# SHA-256 hash mismatch error installing nix for IHP

Tags: macos, nix, ihp

I am trying to install IHP on Mac according to
`https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/installation.html`

When running installation command for nix:
`sh <(curl https://abathur-nix-install-tests.cachix.org/serve/yihf8zbs0jwph2rs9qfh80dnilijxdi2/install) --tarball-url-prefix https://abathur-nix-install-tests.cachix.org/serve`

it fails with the error:
`SHA-256 hash mismatch in 'https://abathur-nix-install-tests.cachix.org/serve/jqr52m6w8dwag5932hw67kq0rvbnji01/nix-2.4pre19700101_eab14a6-x86_64-darwin.tar.xz'; expected @binaryTarball_x86_64-darwin@, got eb40f032d84e2fadb1e875ad7a35a075f9c5b47a4737084a87f925292378b57a`

Comment: This is a bug in IHP's Nix expressions or installation instructions. Please report it in their issue tracker.

Comment: I have reported it at https://github.com/digitallyinduced/ihp/issues/960. The documentation on the web site is reported to be fixed (still cannot see the change  at the moment)

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully installed nix with this command
`sh <(curl -L https://nixos.org/nix/install) --darwin-use-unencrypted-nix-store-volume --daemon`
and one more by following instructions at https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/#sect-macos-installation
After that I installed ihp by using nix.